# Terminal output not displayed for certain commands

Tags: terminal, tty

I'm having a weird problem on Ubuntu 18.04 (Desktop) where certain commands don't display output to the terminal when they are run when they definitely should. I can still capture the output of the command using, e.g., `xclip`. The two commands I'm having this issue for is `systemctl` and `git branch` (but nothing else git-related). I can't figure out what the link is between these two, and I haven't spotted anything else that does this.

For example, if I run:

```
systemctl status cron
```

I don't get output, but if I run:

```
systemctl status cron | xclip -selection clipboard
```

then the status of the cron service is available on my clipboard, as expected.

This happens on both GNOME's terminal and the standard TTY.

Comment: did you play with any environment?  Try `systemctl  --no-pager status cron` option. I am guessing broken $PAGER/$TERM. You can also run `set -x` before one of that command and see what happens when you running such command.

Comment: A broken $PAGER was the issue I think - thanks! $PAGER wasn't set to anything, so I set it to less and everything seems to be back to normal. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sam, proved in comments, solution was check/reset `$PAGER` variable.